# Import/export database (tables) content from/to a CSV file in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, csv

I have a SQL CE database with different tables (Customers, Vendors, etc..). I want to export/import text data to/from these tables to/from a CSV file.

How can I do that?

Comment: For the export I'm trying to use LINQ to get the data and write it in a CSV file in the root folder.